# Set default text alignment in CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor

By default CKEditor assumes that text should be left aligned. If you enable text-align buttons, and select text and align it left, it doesn't change the content at all e.g.

```
Some text >> Some text
```

Whereas selecting center or right alignment adds the appropriate inline styles e.g.

```
Some text >> <div style="text-align:center">Some text</div>
```

The assumption that text is left-aligned by default is not always correct. For example the editor's output may be inside a table cell with align="center". In this case the text will never be left-align-able.

Is there anyway to set the default alignment of text in the CKEditor config prior to instantiating the editor?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the default alignment by changing the contents.css file.

```
body { text-align: center; }
```

Alignment buttons on the toolbar automatically recognize the style and toggle the correct button.

Answer (score 2):

Use this code: `config.contentsLangDirection = 'ltr';` for **Left To Right** alignment and `config.contentsLangDirection = 'rtl';` for **Right To Left**:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {
    ...
    // Default language direction
    config.contentsLangDirection = 'rtl';
    ...
};
```